# Synonym request: multithreading, threading, thread

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The the tags [multithreading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading), [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thread), and [threading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/threading) are duplicates.

[multithreading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) seems to be used the most. I don't see any disadvantage to this (except if a question is only talking about one thread). Can we have these synonym-ized please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant synonyms have been created.